# Parse two numbers - upper digit and unit digit

Tags: c, parsing, real-time

I would like parse two numbers. 
From a RTC IC I get 7 bits, where bit 6, 5, 4 are upper digits (first digit in number of seconds 0 - 5) and bits 3, 2, 1, 0 are unit digits (0 - 9). Now I would like to create a function that parses these two numbers and return the number of seconds.

Here is a table of the second number which I get from the RTC IC. 
[image]

For the first number, I masked these bits and I get upper and lower numbers. I would like to parse these two numbers and return them from a function. 
How?

Comment: Its much like binary to decimal conversion. Did you try anything ?

Comment: Now I have just masking, and then I get two number (int) and now I would like parse this two number (Upper and Low).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward, just split the bits as documented :

```
uint8_t i = getBcd();
return (i >> 4 & 0x7) * 10 + (i & 0xf);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
namespace SOExample
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            // TODO: Implement Functionality Here
            byte ourByte = 89;

            int units = ourByte & 15;
            int tens = ourByte >> 4;

            int result = (int) (tens * 10 + units);


            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong programming language. This answer is off-topic.